# Hitting the suggested edit limit in a review queue is failing silently

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I'm relaying from a post/comments on [meta.askubuntu.com](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17282/the-suggested-edit-quota-is-too-low?cb=1).  The primary part of their question was addressed there; but they did identify a minor bug in the site that should be fixed.

Apparently if a user with limited editing privileges hits their maximum suggested edit limit the edit link on the review page is failing silently instead of informing them that they've hit the maximum number of edits that they can suggest at a time.

At a minimum the error message should be displayed on the review page instead of leaving them confused until they try suggesting an edit on a post directly.

Beyond that, if a user can't submit any more edits, does it still make sense to let them have access to the review queues when a major part of reviewing is temporarily blocked to them?

Comment: As for *Beyond that, if a user can't submit any more edits, does it still make sense to let them have access to the review queues when a major part of reviewing is temporarily blocked to them?*: voting and commenting is still possible. Maybe you can point out in a comment what needs to be edited; otherwise, you can favorite the post and come back later.

Comment: @Glorfindel how many times has the search not being very useful when trying to find a duplicate prior to posting been reported.  :-/

Comment: I can't believe they still haven't done anything about this bug. It's been around for months and has been reported several times, but still hasn't been fixed. When will they fix it?

Comment: @DonaldDuck from prior experience bugs that don't cause serious errors tend to linger for long periods of time before being fixed despite being reported numerous times.  And this one, despite being rather confusing, doesn't actually harm anything; so it's probably at the bottom of the pile.